# Contact form 7- Multi File Upload Values as Links in email

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am using the 'Contact Form 7 Drag and Drop FIles Upload - Multiple Files Upload' (https://codecanyon.net/item/contact-form-7-drag-and-drop-files-upload-multiple-files-upload/20683653) plugin within my form. The uploads could be quite big, so I do not want it attached to the mail but rather have links to the uploaded files in the mail.

I removed the tag from the mail attachment field and added it in the mail body, with the hopes that it will output the uploaded file links:

```
 <p><strong>IMAGES</strong><br/><br/>[dropfiles-291]</a></p>
```

But it only outputs the file names separated by a "|". eg: 'imagename1.jpg|imagename2.jpg|imagename3.jpg|imagename4.jpg'.

After some searching I found this code within the drag and drop plugin code:

```
add_filter('wpcf7_mail_tag_replaced_dropfiles', array($this, 'wpcf7_mail_tag_replaced'), 100, 3);

function wpcf7_mail_tag_replaced($text, $submitted, $html ){
    $upload_dir   = wp_upload_dir();
    $datas = explode("|",$text);
    $url = $upload_dir["baseurl"]."/cf7-uploads-save/";
    $text_custom = array();

    foreach ($datas as $value) {
        $text_custom[] = $url.$value;
    }
    if($html){
        return implode(" <br>", $text_custom);
    }else{
        return implode(" | ", $text_custom);
    }           

}
```

I am not a php developer but the code looks to me like it is supposed to wrap the uploaded files with a link in the email. Hoever, it does not work. And after extensive online research I changed the code to:

```
add_filter('wpcf7_mail_tag_replaced', array($this, 'wpcf7_mail_tag_replaced_dropfiles'), 100, 3);

function wpcf7_mail_tag_replaced_dropfiles( $text, $submitted, $html ){        

    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $datas = explode("|",$text);
    $url = $upload_dir["baseurl"]."/cf7-uploads-save/";
    $text_custom = array();

    foreach ($datas as $value) {
        $text_custom[] = $url.$value;
    }
    if($html){
        return implode(" <br>", $text_custom);}
        else{return implode(" | ", $text_custom);}               

}
```

The email now has the desired link effect but on ALL the submitted fields in the form, not just the [dropfiles] fields. The [dropfiles] fields looks great with each uploaded file's link in a new line etc. But I, obviously, don't also want the normal text, textarea, checkbox, radio etc fields to also be links.

I have sent a support ticket to the plugin developer but have not heard anything back yet. What approach can I take to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a temp solution - just until I get a permanent solution from the plugin developer. I changed the code as follows:

```
add_filter('wpcf7_mail_tag_replaced', array($this, 'wpcf7_mail_tag_replaced_dropfiles'), 100, 3);

function wpcf7_mail_tag_replaced_dropfiles( $text, $submitted, $html ){        
if(preg_match('/\.(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$/', $submitted))  {
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $datas = explode("|",$text);
    $url = $upload_dir["baseurl"]."/cf7-uploads-save/";
    $text_custom = array();

    foreach ($datas as $value) {
        $text_custom[] = $url.$value;
    }
    if($html){
        return implode(" <br>", $text_custom);}
        else{return implode(" | ", $text_custom);}               
    } 

    return $text; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've spent HOURS bugging this issue but I think I've found the problem.

I noticed it just happened when I used the dropfiles tag as a required field. [dropfiles* ...]

Contact Form 7 has a function "replace_tags_callback" that applies the filter "wpcf7_mail_tag_replaced_{$type}".

The problem is that {$type} is getting from $form_tag->type, which in our case can be both "dropfiles" or "dropfiles*". If CF7 got it using $form_tag->basetype it would be the same for both tags.

So to fix the problem I added a filter for "dropfiles*" on line 7 in contact-form-7-drop-files/frontend/index.php

```
add_filter('wpcf7_mail_tag_replaced_dropfiles*', array($this, 'wpcf7_mail_tag_replaced'), 100, 3);
```

So the beginning of the class is now like this:

```
function __construct(){
    add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts",array($this,"add_lib"));
    add_filter('wpcf7_form_response_output', array($this,'add_settings'),999999,4);
    add_filter('wpcf7_mail_tag_replaced_dropfiles', array($this, 'wpcf7_mail_tag_replaced'), 100, 3);
    add_filter('wpcf7_mail_tag_replaced_dropfiles*', array($this, 'wpcf7_mail_tag_replaced'), 100, 3);
}
function wpcf7_mail_tag_replaced($text, $submitted, $html ){
    $upload_dir   = wp_upload_dir();
    $datas = explode("|",$text);
    $url = $upload_dir["baseurl"]."/cf7-uploads-save/";
    $text_custom = array();

    foreach ($datas as $value) {
        $text_custom[] = $url.$value;
    }
    if($html){
        return implode(" <br>", $text_custom);
    }else{
        return implode(" | ", $text_custom);
    }



}
```

I reported the bug to the plugin author and hope he/she'll update it in the next version.